# How can I dynamically add markers in google map using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a flutter project that requires the user to interact with business outlets within the area that he or she is in. The code that I have requires me to statically input the latitude and longitude coordinates of the businesses. Is there a way I can fetch the coordinate information directly from firebase and display it in google maps? Below is the code snippet of the static code. Any help would be of assistance. Thanks

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
        markers:

        markers,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        zoomControlsEnabled: false,
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
          newgoogleMapController = controller;
          blackThemeGoogleMap();
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await _determinePosition();
          newgoogleMapController?.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
                  zoom: 14)));
          markers.clear();
          markers.add(
            Marker(
              markerId: const MarkerId('Current Location'),
              position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'My Position',
              ),
            ),
          );
          markers.add(
             Marker(
              markerId: const MarkerId('Mash AutoGarage'),
              position: const LatLng(-1.113418, 37.0224462),
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'Mash AutoGarage',
              ),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
            ),
          );
          // markers.add(
          //   const Marker(
          //     markerId: MarkerId('Mash AutoGarage'),
          //     position: LatLng(-1.113418, 37.0224462),
          //     infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          //       title: 'Mash AutoGarage',
          //     ),
          //   ),
          // );
          markers.add(
             Marker(
              markerId:const MarkerId('Test Garage'),
              position: const LatLng(-1.113418, 37.0224462),
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'Test Garage',
              ),
               icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
            ),
          );
          markers.add(
             Marker(
              markerId: const MarkerId('Tester Description'),
              position: const LatLng(-1.1132872999999999, 37.0216026),
              infoWindow: const InfoWindow(
                title: 'Tester Description',
              ),
               icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),
            ),
          );

          setState(() {});
        },
        label: const Text('Current Location'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.location_history),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is this all being called in your build method, or a method called by build?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to:

1. Load the lat/lon values from Firestore as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).
2. Store the lat/lon values in variables in your stateful widget.
3. Call `setState()` to inform Flutter that it needs to rebuild the UI, as shown [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).
4. Use the lat/lon variables in your `build` method.